# Exit automatically powershell after executing a command

Tags: powershell

I want to execute for example "code ." in PowerShell, and add second commend to exit PowerShell window.

Can somebody help?

I tried :

> code . & exit

> code . && exit

But it is not working...

Comment: "code ." is the command to open Visual Studio Code".

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a good one. Sometimes we want to use PowerShell or Cmd to execute specific command and then close the Window.

Here is what I suggest:

> code .; exit

You should use ";" instead of "&&", this last one is for Cmd.

It works for me that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please keep your answer as concise as possible, possibly by removing first and last lines

Comment: too much irrelevant details